# Linked List sort

Tags: java, sorting

I saw your response for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538652/adding-an-element-to-a-sorted-list-and-keeping-it-sorted-in-ascending-order-jav this thread.

How do you find the position of the inserting element?

I'm a school student trying with linked lists for first time but I can understand at beginning or end but how to find right position when you already have sequence?

```
public void insertFirstPosition(int newElement)
    {  
        ListOfNVersion03 temp = new ListOfNVersion03(thisNumber);
        temp.next = next;
        next = temp;
        thisNumber = newElement;

    }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Use proper formatting. For code.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the list which you have is already sorted ...

Then iterate with a loop from one link to the next. While iterating you store the previous node. When you find the first node which is worst than the node you want to insert. change the previous node next to the inserting node and the inserting node references the current node.

```
// Pseudocode
Node previousNode = root;
while (previousNode.next != null) {
    Node current = previousNode.next;
    // Check current node
    if (current.value < insert.value) {
        previousNode.next = insert;
        insert.next = current;
        break;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to handle also the case insert at the end

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a linked list, you have to go through the nodes one by one and compare the number you are inserting to find the position.

```
public Link findLink(int n){
 Link lk= firstLink;
 while (lk!=null){
    if (lk.number<n)
    return lk;
    lk=lk.next;
    }
 return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedList class extends AbstractSequentialList and implements the List interface. It provides a linked-list data structure.

Apart from the methods inherited from its parent classes, LinkedList defines following methods:

> void add(int index, Object element) Inserts the specified element at
>   the specified position index in this list. Throws
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException if the specified index is is out of range
>   (index < 0 || index > size()).
>
> void addFirst(Object o) Inserts the given element at the beginning of
>   this list.
>
> void addLast(Object o) Appends the given element to the end of this
>   list
>
> Object get(int index) Returns the element at the specified position in
>   this list. Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the specified index is
>   is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()).

I will Show you the Example code.this May helps you,

```
import java.util.*;
public class LinkedListDemo{ public static void main(String args[])
{// create a linked list
LinkedList ll =new LinkedList();// add elements to the linked list
      ll.add("F");
      ll.add("B");
      ll.add("D");
      ll.add("E");
      ll.add("C");
      ll.addLast("Z");
      ll.addFirst("A");
      ll.add(1,"A2");
System.out.println("Original contents of ll: "+ ll);// remove elements from the linked list
      ll.remove("F");
      ll.remove(2);
System.out.println("Contents of ll after deletion: "+ ll);// remove first and last elements
      ll.removeFirst();
      ll.removeLast();
System.out.println("ll after deleting first and last: "+ ll);// get and set a valueObject val = ll.get(2);
      ll.set(2,(String) val +" Changed");
System.out.println("ll after change: "+ ll);
}
}
```

If you have doubt about Linked list, please search about Data Structures on java..thank you
..Vote me back.!